# How can I fold SCSS map literals in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, sass

It there is way to fold map structures in VS Code?

For example:

```
@return map.deep-merge(
    mat.define-light-theme($theme),
    (
        color: (
            foreground: (
                text: map-get(blui.$blui-black, 500),
            ),
        ),
        foreground: (
            onPrimary: map-get(blui.$blui-white, 50),
            onAccent: map-get(blui.$blui-white, 50),
            onWarn: map-get(blui.$blui-white, 50),
            text: map-get(blui.$blui-black, 500),
            secondary-text: map-get(blui.$blui-gray, 500),
            hint-text: map-get(blui.$blui-gray, 500),
            base: map-get(blui.$blui-darkBlack, 900),
            divider: rgba(map-get(blui.$blui-black, 500), 0.12),
            disabled: rgba(map-get(blui.$blui-black, 500), 0.3),
            icon: rgba(black, 0.54),
            icons: rgba(black, 0.54),
        ),
        background: (
            card: map-get(blui.$blui-white, 50),
            dialog: map-get(blui.$blui-white, 50),
            disabled-button: rgba(114, 126, 132, 0.12),
            disabled-button-toggle: map-get(blui.$blui-gray, 200),
        ),
    )
);
```

Comment: can you please show some example code? How will we know how _you've_ written your maps? Is SCSS a whitespace/indentation-sensitive language? (I thought not?)

Comment: If you want a solution that doesn't depend on indentation, you can consider [writing a feature-request to VS Code](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/new?assignees=&labels=&projects=&template=feature_request.md). I tried searching to see if one had already been made by googling "`github vscode issues folding for scss maps`" and "`site:github.com vscode issues folding for "SCSS" maps`" and didn't see anything that looked like one in the top few search results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an interesting idea :

```
"[scss]": {
    "editor.foldingStrategy": "indentation"
},
```

It tell VSCode to use identation to determine where to fold. That does the job for me !

Comment: related on reddit: https://www.reddit.com/r/vscode/comments/qidaq5/expand_and_collapse_for_sassscss_maps/